# When do we see Gungans in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, behind-the-scenes

[image: Screenshot from [“The Force Awakens”] Comic-Con video.]

In this screenshot from *The Force Awakens* Comic-Con [behind the scenes video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTNJ51ghzdY), the red arrows point to what look like models/drawings of **[gungans](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gungan)**, implying that there would be gungans appearing in the film.

[image]

However I don't remember seeing any. Were there any gungans in the film?

---

<sub>Note: I'm asking about *any* gungan, not just ... *that* gungan.</sub>

Comment: If there is anything good and decent in the world, we will only see Gungans when they are being roasted alive and devoured by Ewoks.

Comment: @WadCheber No Ewoks in TFA either, [thanks to Harrison Ford](http://comicbook.com/2015/12/07/no-jar-jar-binks-or-ewoks-in-star-wars-the-force-awakens/).

Comment: I've updated my answer (but not my conclusion) based on your proposed green line interpretation! Glad I caught it.

Comment: Another update with a shot of the actual aliens as we see them in the movie

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Update

Per the *Creating Creatures* featurette on the Blu-ray, we find out that these aliens were dubbed "snooty pirates" and definitely not Gungans. Here's a pic I took since I can't screencap it.

[image]

---

#### **I would say that not only were Gungans not seen in *The Force Awakens*, but they should not have been expected to.**

Based on (1) lack of evidence to the contrary, (2) my personal viewing of the film, and (3) my counter-points to the images in question.

1. Jar Jar was the only Gungan character mentioned in pre-production, although as [@Praxis's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112912/31178) shows, that idea was scrapped before the behind-the-scenes video was released on YouTube. The studio scene could have been filmed before Jar Jar was axed (not in the way we hoped), so this point alone isn't enough.
2. I did not see any Gungans while viewing the film, even though I was on the lookout for [Darth Jar Jar](http://darthjarjar.com/) or his cohorts. (I don't believe the theory, but I was hoping for a detail that'd spur more ridiculousness!)
3. I would posit that the picture creatures were not meant to be Gungans at all. My analysis follows:

[image]

After looking at the updated question, with outlines, I see that I was looking at the negative space in a completely different way that the OP. So, I drew these overlays to help me see it their way.

[image] [image]

**After doing this, I would hazard that the sketch on the right is meant to be the same species or character as the prop on the left.**

I can't guess which other character in *TFA* this was. There were a few scenes with many alien species, such as on Jakku or at Maz's place, and images of them *all* aren't available to me, yet. I *can* provide a comparison of the character designs to Gungan designs.

[image]

As you can see above, snouted Gungans like Jar Jar have:

- Eyes attached to short stalk-like anatomy, rising much above the skull line. The eyes on the drawing seem to match the ones on the prop, and neither have the stalk, ergo one probably wasn't added later
- Wide, flat mouths that extend back up the snout, unlike the puckered orifice in the studio image
- Visible nostril holes and ridges halfway up the snout (I can't spot anything like them in the studio pics)
- A cranial ridge running from behind the eyes and down into the lips
- A short, steep cranial slope, as opposed to the long, shallow one seen in the studio
- No clear cheekbones, which *are* evident to me below the eye ridge on the left prop

Then there's the ears. Jar Jar's type of Gungan seems to sport different ones than his escort, so I'll account for both types:

The prop on the left currently has no ears long or large enough to be construed as Gungan ears, and the existing cap would likely interfere with attaching such ears to the model, unless it's easily removable. To me, they look like ears or a cloak for a different species, but I'm going to write this model off as too unclear.

The drawing on the right has what looks like large ears, but they fail to be Gungan because:

- Unlike Jar Jar's or Tarpal's ear's, the primary outer ridge has no visible segmentation or ribbing. Some of these details could be lost, but I think the segmentation near the base of the ears would be noticeable, based on other visible details in the image.
- Unlike the Gungan guard's "ears", they are not wide, loose, or resting on the shoulders. This type of Gungan's head appendage naturally rests in line with the center of the neck on the [frontal plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_terms_of_location#Planes). The drawing's rest behind the shoulders, but without any of the thick, floppiness we'd expect from this type of Gungan if they brushed it back.

One or two points of difference in a design comparison might not be enough to rule out Gungan design, given that there are several types of Gungans themselves. However, the difference between these behind-the-scenes designs and known Gungan designs are significant enough to rule them out as Gungans, unless we were going to be introduced to yet another variety. I think a new variety would be unlike, and, ahem, alienate the fan base.

---

The one on the right originally looked a bit like Boss Nass to me:

[image] [image]

So, I thought that's what the OP was referring to. I personally thought it looked much more like the big gentlemen we see in Maz Kanata's place, as pictured in the center of this image:

[image]

[image] [image]

If you look closely at the sketch, you can even see a thin cord coming from the top right (character's left) across his chest, which the tusked alien also has.

I no longer think the drawing is meant to be a [fat-headed](http://rockosmodernlife.wikia.com/wiki/The_Fatheads) aliens, but wanted to preserve this part in case someone else saw the sketch without paintovers and saw the same thing as I did.

Comment: Would you mind adding a TL;DR? Could be just me being tired, but it took me 3 re-reads and 10 minutes to understand your answer to "when" is "never" :)

Comment: @DVK The conclusion is at the bottom, where conclusions go! And it's bold text! I have a thing against TL;DR. :/

Comment: ah, got it. Too much business writing - I am more used to starting executive summary than ending summary. Please consider doing the summary in "##" header font, given the post length, for better visibility? I don't insist, so won't edit it in myself.

Comment: @DVK I do executive summaries at times, but the structure of this post is all over the place right now, because I've written it from 2 locations and at weird times of the day. It'll look prettier when I get to formatting it tomorrow.

Comment: good luck. I am too tired to appreciate its correctness ATM but it does look like an awsome bit of research.

Comment: Did you draw the turquoise lines yourself or is there an app/programs you used?

Comment: @RedCaio Quick sketch in Photoshop with a Wacom tablet.

Answer (score 9):

## We don't, but J.J. thought about killing off Jar Jar in *The Force Awakens*.

I have seen *The Force Awakens* twice and did not spot any Gungans.  Also, the Alan Dean Foster novelization does not include "Gungan" or "Jar Jar" or "Binks" anywhere in the text.  It was also [confirmed about 10 days before theatrical release](http://www.digitaltrends.com/movies/jar-jar-binks-wont-appear-in-the-force-awakens/) that Jar Jar wouldn't be in the film.

It is worth noting, however, that as recently as May 2015 (only 7 months prior to the film's release), Director J.J. Abrams had considered killing off Jar Jar in the film, as a fan service:

- [The Guardian: JJ Abrams considers killing off Jar Jar Binks](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2015/may/06/jj-abrams-considers-killing-off-jar-jar-binks-star-wars)

It is possible that the prosthetic in the screenshot was constructed in preparation for such a scene.  According to the linked article, J.J. mainly considered having a shot of Jar Jar's bones lying in the desert; still, he could have been considering other methods of killing him off (e.g. having him on the balcony at Hosnian Prime).

Comment: It was [confirmed](http://www.digitaltrends.com/movies/jar-jar-binks-wont-appear-in-the-force-awakens/) even pre-release that Jar Jar wouldn't be in the film.

Comment: @randal'thor : Thanks, I'll add that in.  :-)

Comment: it is a possibly now though, as new canon novel "Empire's End" reveals that Jar Jar Binks is alive and living on Naboo post ROTJ