# Was Boss Nass a Gungan?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace, prequels

I'll admit that this seems a silly question, but after observing the images from [this recent question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112909/when-do-we-see-gungans-in-the-force-awakens) I had the obvious realization that other than skin tone and dress, Boss Nass looks absolutely nothing like other Gungans!  He seems to be missing the tell-tale long ears, his eyes are inset rather than protruded and, unless my recollection is off, not a single other Gungan is overweight.

Of course, the weight can be explained away by simply claiming he's the leader and, therefore, has free-reign to all resources available, especially food.  However, even the rest of the [Gungan Council](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/swfanon/images/5/51/GunganCouncil.jpg) at the beginning of the Phantom Menace doesn't appear to have such weight issues which, in my opinion, makes Boss Nass's form all the more odd.

I considered writing off this question but being that there is precedent within the Star Wars universe of creatures setting up other beings not of their species as [leaders](http://cdn.smosh.com/sites/default/files/bloguploads/sw-hover-returnofthejedi.jpg), it didn't seem to off base of an assumption.

Comment: He ties his ears together like a ponytail but they're still back there if you look really closely/have the action figure ;)

Comment: That makes sense.  his hat didn't seem big enough for them to be stuffed into, some how. :P

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your confusion likely stems from the fact that Boss Nass (and several of the other bosses) were [Ankura](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ankura) Gungans, as opposed to Jar Jar who was an [Otolla](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Otolla) Gungan.

> *“Boss,” Leika amended. “Boss Ganne. **An Ankura Gungan — the ones with
>   green skin and hooded eyes**.”* - <sub><sup>[SW: The Phanton Menace - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_(novel))</sup></sub>

Per Wookieepedia

> *The Ankura were one of the two major races of the Gungan species,
>   denoted by their shorter bill and haillu, hooded eyes, and stockier
>   build. They were an older race than the lanky Otolla. Boss Nass was a
>   typical Ankura Gungan.*

and

> *The Otolla were one of the two major races of the Gungan species. They
>   were characterized by their tall and usually lanky bodies, longer
>   haillu, prominent bills, and inquisitive eyes that sat up on short
>   stalks. The Otolla were a younger race than the bulkier Ankura. Jar
>   Jar Binks was a typical Otolla.*

and from the [Star Wars Episode I Visual Dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0789447010)

> ***Boss Nass has the distinctive green skin and hooded eyes of the old
>   Ankura lineage that hails from an isolated swamp village.*** His distant
>   ancestors united with the Otolla Gungans who founded Otoh Gunga

Comment: The prequel trilogy was big on speces split into 2 classes. The other big example that jumps out to me is Utapau, which had 2 extremely different subsets of the same species.

Comment: Useful. Is it known if the Gungans have a formal caste system?

Comment: @DukeZhou - Not a formal system, no. But the leaders of the Gungan High Council are invariably Ankura Gungans (and have been for centuries), despite the Council mainly comprising Otolla Gungans.

Answer (score 17):

### Yes, the Star Wars databank specifically identifies his species as a Gungan.

[image: boss nass bio]
<sup>[source](http://www.starwars.com/databank/boss-nass)</sup>

Comment: Ah, ok.  I had read the write-up and was about to rebut, but then I noticed the "Species" tag at the bottom.  I'd not seen or noticed that.

Comment: @RLH yeah, the text in the blurb is ambiguous, but his species is clearly stated. i added a fancy red arrow to help draw attention.

Comment: If I hadn't already upvoted, you'd certainly be getting it simple for the Paint arrow!

Comment: -1 because no hand-drawn circle :)

Comment: Compared to the [other answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112964/21137), this one is somewhat lacking with respect to the specific points raised in the question.