# Does Star Wars society differentiate between race?

Tags: star-wars, races

Individuals in Star Wars society differentiate between species, that is for sure. The Galactic Empire discriminates against non-humans. However, does the concept of race/ethnic relations exist in-universe? Does Han perceive Lando as "different" or does he see Lando as purely "just another human"?

Besides human races, which we can identify due to real world experience, do we know of other races/ethnicities in other species in-universe?

Comment: See [Was Boss Nass a Gungan?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112962/5184) for an example of something similar to races/ethnicities within species.

Comment: Racial distinctions on Earth are based on local climate conditions and the fact that groups of people lived in a specific area for thousands of years without much interaction with outsiders. Since the last hundred years or so has made free movement around the globe possible for all, we may see more and more blending of characteristics as we intermarry. An interesting question is, on a planet like Tatooine with one climate, would different races even develop?

Comment: @CigarDoug I think that can be answered by first asking: Are there multiple races/ethnicities in Africa?

Comment: You might also want to look into how perceptions of "race" have changed in the last few hundred years on Earth. There was a time when people acted like an island the size of Britain alone was home to multiple difference "races" and would claim to be able to identify e.g. a Cornishman, by appearance. Nowadays, almost everyone lumps all Europeans together as a single unit.

Comment: @thegreatjedi if you use the three race categorization I learned in school (negroid, caucasiod, mongoloid); then no. But I have always asked the question: What are Mexicans and Latin Americans? What are Egyptians? What are Arabs? Clearly Arabs look different than African blacks, but they are considered white, right? Asians definitely look different from each other as well. You wouldn't mistake a Samoan for a Thai.

Comment: Methinks I opened a larger conversation than expected.

Answer (score 6):

In the films (and canon cartoons) a number of species seem to have races based on differences in skin colours.

These include:

### Twi'leks

Twi'leks definitely appear to have different races with big varieties in skin colours and lekku shapes.

**Oola - Return of the Jedi**

[image: oola 1]

**Aayla Secura - Attack of the Clones & Revenge of the Sith**

[image: ayla secura 2]

**Orn Free Taa - The Phantom Menace, Attack of the Clones & Revenge of the Sith**

[image: Twi'lek 3]

**Bib Fortuna - Return of the Jedi**

[image: bib fortuna]

### Togruta

Togruta also appear to have races based on differences in skin colour, all on the red side of the spectrum (reds, oranges, yellows).

**Ahsoka Tano - Rebels**

[image: ashoka tano]

**Shaak Ti - Attack of the Clones & Revenge of the Sith**

[image: shak ti]

### Humans

Humans are displayed as a variety of races, Black, Caucasian, Asian.

**Lando Calrissian - The Empire Strikes Back & The Return of the Jedi**

[image: lando]

**Mace Windu - The Phantom Menace, Attack of the Clones & Revenge of the Sith**

[image: mace Windu]

**Obi-Wan Kenobi - All the films in one form or another**

[image: the Kenobi]

**Han Solo - A New Hope, The Empire Strikes Back, Return of the Jedi & The Force Awakens**

[image: shooting first]

**Kanjiklub - The Force Awakens**

[image: Kanjiklub]

Nothing ever seems to be mentioned regarding races. One would assume with a wide variety of species throughout the galaxy racism within species would have given way to speciesism against those with far greater differences than mere skin colour.

Comment: Could you include names of all characters pictured, and perhaps movie or show they appear in.

Comment: @CreationEdge done

Comment: Darth Maul's heavy Tattooing was not a normal cultural practice as I remember. They were applied as a baby with his brother Opress.

Comment: If the pictures of Orn Free Taa and Bib Fortunate are anything to go by, Twi’leks also differ according to race in number of digits—Bib seems to have only four fingers (unless there's an extra one that's just cleverly hidden).

Comment: Afaik Zabraks aren't Nightbrothers. And Maul's appearance is the result of Mother Talzin's magic

Comment: @thegreatjedi I will take Zabraks out then I wasn't sure if we would class them as different races, as the only different coloured ones I've seen have been in legends canon

Comment: It is not so rare that humans are born with extra or missing digits but one would not classify their race based on that - consider [these people](http://topyaps.com/top-10-famous-people-with-extra-fingers-or-toes). So i'm not sure this argument applies here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet this could be a case of sexual dimorphism as it is the males with the less fingers

Comment: Bib Fortuna always looks like he has a single lekku, my brain keeps telling me he's thus not a Twi'lek. Also found this interesting tidbit about [Lekku](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lekku):

A Twi'lek's headtails served many purposes in their daily lives and culture, storing fat and other qualities. The Twi'lek's native language was spoken using a combination of words and subtle movements of the lekku